# "<<<<<<< HEAD" no meio do código após fazer merge

Tags: git

Fui fazer `merge` entre a `branch` `develop` e `master` e apareceram alguns conflitos, mas acabei resolvendo. O problema é que vi dois arquivos em que tem `<<<<<<< HEAD` no meio do código da `branch` `master`. Acabei retirando essa parte manualmente, mas como foram vários arquivos afetados no `merge`, acho que pode ter mais alguns com esse problema.

Achei que ao fazer `merge` novamente isso iria arrumar, pois a `develop` não possui esses erros, então apagaria da `master`, mas não modifica nada (apenas novas alterações).

Teria alguma forma de corrigir isso? Ou até mesmo na hora de fazer `merge` substituir todos os arquivos da `master` pela `develop`?

Answer (score 4):

Esse é o indicador de conflito. Se você der um `git status` poderá verificar que está no meio de uma solução de conflitos ainda. Ou se você não estiver... significa que fez lambança. Significa que você commitou uma "solução de conflito" que incluía esse marcador (junto com o `=======` e o `>>>>>>>>> develop`).

O git só faz essa marca quando ele não consegue se virar sozinho para resolver as mudanças. O caso em que o git não sabe lidar com isso é quando há duas mudanças no mesmo contexto.

Por exemplo, imagina que eu tenho esse código C-símile:

```c
if (num % 2 == 1)
```

Então, no `develop`, alguém altera para:

```c
if (num % 2)
```

Mas eu, no `master` altero para:

```c
if (num & 1)
```

Como o git vai proceder? Ele vai identificar que a base comum dos dois códigos era:

```c
if (num % 2 == 1)
```

> Nota para os próximos parágrafos: linha de código prefixada com `-` indica linha **removida**, já linha prefixada com `+` indica linha **acrescentada**

Que o `develop` é a seguinte operação:

```c
-    if (num % 2 == 1)
+    if (num % 2)
```

É que a mudança no `master` é a seguinte operação:

```c
-    if (num % 2 == 1)
+    if (num & 1)
```

Isso significa que houve duas ações distintas

> ```c
> -    if (num % 2 == 1)
> +    if (num % 2)
> ```
>
> e
>
> ```c
> -    if (num % 2 == 1)
> +    if (num & 1)
> ```

para o mesmo contexto (linha original `if (num % 2 == 1)`). O máximo que o git consegue de informação daqui é que a linha original foi removida, mas ele não saberá qual ação deve ser tomada. Para isso, ele vai gerar mais ou menos o seguinte após a tentativa de merge (`git merge develop`):

```c
<<<<<<<<<< HEAD
    if (num & 1)
==========
    if (num % 2)
>>>>>>>>>> develop
```

Com isso, cabe ao humano decidir o que vai fazer com isso é, então, e somente então, comunicar ao git que o conflito foi resolvido. Esse caso de conflito se resolve fazendo `git add meu/arquivo/conflito.c` para elencar cada resolução de conflito, então confirmada com um `git commit` tradicional.

Esse de longe é o caso de conflito mais comum que eu tenho no desenvolvimento na empresa onde trabalho. Existem outros casos de conflito, com mudanças no mesmo contexto, tipo, eu alterei o arquivo mas o Articuno resolveu apagá-lo em seu branch. Ao tentar mergear, o git reclamará que houve um conflito do tipo "mudança/remoção".

Às vezes o conflito não implica em que ambas as cabeças tenha de fato apagado a mesma linha e inserido a sua mudança. Já tive caso de conflitos assim:

Arquivo base:

```c
int x;
int a;
```

Cabeça `patch-1`:

```c
int x;
-int a;
+int a = 2;
```

Cabeça `patch-2`:

```c
int x;
int a;
+char *palavra;
```

Nesse caso, o pós merge seria algo semelhante a isso:

```c
int x;
<<<<<<<<<< HEAD
int a = 2;
==========
int a;
char *palavra;
>>>>>>>>>> patch-2
```

Note que aqui o git ficou confuso quanto à remoção ou não da linha `int a;`, pois em um dos branches ela realmente fora excluída, enquanto no outro eu apenas anexei a ela.

Comment: O git status mostra que não tem nada para fazer commit. Agora pra remover isso só manualmente?

Comment: @DiegoVieira você já empurrou as mudanças? Se sim, você seria capaz de fazer um _force push_? Eu recomendaria reescrever o histórico e remover esse merge, para então realizar um novo merge e só terminá-lo quando estiver tudo **devidamente** resolvido, e empurrar depois disso. Agora, acho que não deixei muito claro, mas esse processo de merge, no momento em que o git detecta mudanças no mesmo contexto, é **todo** manual, devendo **sempre** ser resolvido por um humano. Se isso está no arquivo, é sinal que o humano não resolveu adequadamente o conflito na hora do merge.

Comment: Você pode fazer um commit normal com edições de texto removendo essas linhas, mas fica no histórico essa vergonha para sempre

Comment: Sim, as mudanças já estão em produção. Foi estupidez minha. Por causa dos erros, acabei removendo manualmente dos arquivos que encontrei. E agora estou procurando um por um para ver se deixei passar algum com esse problema.